# Matching BIT to DATETIME in CASE statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, case-statement

I'm attempting to create a T-SQL case statement to filter a query based on whether a field is `NULL` or if it contains a value. It would be simple if you could assign `NULL` or `NOT NULL` as the result of a case but that doesn't appear possible.

Here's the psuedocode:

```
WHERE DateColumn = CASE @BitInput
   WHEN 0 THEN (all null dates)
   WHEN 1 THEN (any non-null date)
   WHEN NULL THEN (return all rows)
```

From my understanding, the `WHEN 0` condition can be achieved by not providing a `WHEN` condition at all (to return a `NULL` value).

The `WHEN 1` condition seems like it could use a wildcard character but I'm getting an error regarding type conversion. Assigning the column to itself fixes this.

I have no idea what to do for the `WHEN NULL` condition. My internal logic seems to think assigning the column to itself should solve this but it does not as stated above.

I have recreated this using dynamic SQL but for various reasons I'd prefer to have it created in the native code.

I'd appreciate any input. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CASE expression (as OMG Ponies said) is mixing and matching datatypes (as you spotted), in addition you can not compare to NULL using `=` or WHEN.

```
WHERE
   (@BitInput = 0 AND DateColumn IS NULL)
   OR
   (@BitInput = 1 AND DateColumn IS NOT NULL)
   OR
   @BitInput IS NULL
```

You could probably write it using CASE but what you want is an OR really.

You can also use `IF..ELSE` or `UNION ALL` to separate the 3 cases

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar not to mention my personal hero for the day. Thanks for the quick response.